# MySQL : limit the number of clients served concurrently

Tags: mysql, memory

1. I am experiencing a problem where the server runs out of memory in specific scenarios.
   one solution I am thinking about is to limit the number of clients served concurrently, but have the extra clients wait for a free slot instead of having them get a "too many connections error".
   is this possible?
2. how do I calculate maximum memory usage per open mysql connection?

Answer (score 3):

take a look in my.cnf (should be somewhere in /etc or /etc/mysql, depending on your distro); there you have several options for fine tuning, like

- max_connections
- max_connect_errors
- max_delayed_threads
- max_user_connections

and some query cache options

Comment: this does not really answer my question.
limiting max_connections results in an error if the number of connections is reached (instead of the desired 'wait for a free slot' behavior).

Comment: I don't think you can setup a waiting queue; all connections coming after the "slots" have been filled up are discarded

Answer (score 0):

How much memory is the database using?  How much is installed?  What OS are you running MySQL on?

Comment: Debian lenny, and the machine has 4GB of RAM and is also doing other things.
lets assume mysql cannot handle the peak usage (with the required max_allowed_packet - there are big inserts).
is there a way to achieve what I specified by tweaking mysql?

Comment: key_buffer              = 512M
max_allowed_packet      = 64M
thread_stack            = 128K
thread_cache_size       = 32K
max_connections         = 350
table_cache            = 256
thread_concurrency     = 8

sort_buffer_size        = 64M
wait_timeout            = 20

query_cache_limit       = 64M
query_cache_size        = 512M
query_alloc_block_size  = 4M
query_prealloc_size     = 128M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M
##########
try those or modify the left values to your needs

Comment: If changing those settings doesn't correct the issue, you may need to increase the amount of RAM in the server.  4 Gigs for a busy server isn't a whole lot.